# Maven archetype variable replacement for custom files

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to build a custom archetype and we have some custom files with extension .props.

The file name can be substituted like this:

```
__artifactId__.props
```

but I'm not able to use any variable like ${artifactId} inside of this prop file.

The archetype-metadata.xml file has right property set

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactId" />
```

Files with xml extensions work without an issue. I can use the ${artifactId} annotation inside of the xml files. So how do I get it working for custom files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it the archetype-metadata.xml needs to have the filtered=true attribute set.

```
<fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
        <directory>deployment/dev</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.props</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```